# Most effective means of PHP AD Authentication?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Our company is looking at moving authentication from our web app which is PHP running on Apache in Windows, and would like to authenticate using Active Directory. I have a way to simply pull your username that you're already authenticated with, but I have no experience with actually authenticating.

Reading up it looks like LDAP would be the way to go. My question is as follows:

Is LDAP the best way to authenticate in a PHP web app using Active Directory credentials?
Is there a different setup I should go to perhaps using PHP and IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.davidschultz.org/2008/04/10/how-to-authenticate-against-active-directory-using-php/

^ this will show you how to authenticate against AD with PHP.

I don't know that this is better or worse than LDAP, but it seems pretty easy. Though, read through the comments first--it's probably not a good idea to hit AD on each page load but rather store a value somewhere to check against as one of the comments suggests.

Comment: Thanks - I discovered I was severely over complicating things. I got it working.

Comment: Good to hear. I tend to overcomplicate things too. Though it may not be efficient, it's a great way to learn stuff :)